# OpenWRT - How to redirect all subdomains of a hostname, to the same host, so that it can be reverse proxied?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, reverse-proxy, subdomain, openwrt

I have an OpenWRT router setup, `192.168.1.1`, with search domain, `local` (as opposed to the default `lan`).

I have a server setup, `192.168.1.200`, with hostname, `server.local`.

I have a workstation, `192.168.1.10`, with hostname, `workstation.local`.

`server.local` also operates an NGINX reverse proxy, to provide subdomains such as, `sub.server.local`.

If my workstation tries to access, `server.local`, it is resolved correctly to point at `192.168.1.200`.

However, if my workstation tries to access, `sub.server.local`, it can't resolve to `192.168.1.200`.

If my workstation has `192.168.1.200  sub.server.local`, added to its hosts file, it resolves correctly, and the servers reverse proxy routes the incoming connection to the correct port.

How do I fix this, so that all subdomains of `server.local` resolve to `192.168.1.200`? Without having to add a hosts record to every workstation, for every subdomain on the server, which is obviously not sustainable.

I'm assuming that I need to alter some DNS records on my OpenWRT router, but looking through the settings in Luci (the web interface), nothing sticks out as being capable of achieving this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sorted it out eventually.

According to:

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration#a_and_aaaa_rr

Which states:

> This is an implementation of the --address option. Return 10.10.10.1 on query domain home and subdomain *.home.

I was able to login to OpenWRT (using `ssh root@192.168.1.1`), and running:

```
uci add_list dhcp.@dnsmasq[0].address="/server.local/192.168.1.200"
uci commit dhcp
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Which then allows the following to work:

```
~$ ping www.server.local

PING www.server.local (192.168.1.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server.local (192.168.1.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=55.4 ms
64 bytes from server.local (192.168.1.200): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=77.3 ms
```

And anything else for that matter:

```
~$ ping hdsjdjk.server.local

PING hdsjdjk.server.local (192.168.1.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server.local (192.168.1.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=101 ms
64 bytes from server.local (192.168.1.200): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=124 ms
```

As I understand it, this creates an A record in DNSMasq, which automatically includes all subdomains.

The changes can be seen in `/etc/config/dhcp`, which now looks (partially) like:

```
config dnsmasq
        [...]
        option domain 'local'
        option local '/local/'
        list address '/server.local/192.168.1.200'

[...]
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: What about if the domains are : 

- `lan` : `192.168.8.*` my local lan domain (all dhcp assigned hosts are here)
- `someo.ne`: `???.???.???.???` a website hosted on netlify, dns controlled by cloudflare
- `*.someo.ne` `192.168.8.222` a set of hosts hosted by my local k8s cluster

Comment: For anyone setting the `address` option to resolve some arbitrary FQDN (ie. an FQDN with a top level domain not matching that specified in the `domain` / `local` options) to some local IP, for example `list address '/mydomain.com/192.168.1.200'`, I would also recommend setting `list server '/mydomain.com/'` preventing dnsmasq forwarding requests for that domain and will also speed up resolution for that domain as otherwise you will be waiting for the remote dns lookups to come back. This is particularly bad if the remote dns cannot be reached in which case youll be waiting for the timeout.

Answer (score 5):

As of today<sup>*</sup>, this is available in Luci: under Network -> DHCP and DNS -> General, field Addresses

[image: Luci Network -> DHCP and DNS -> General -> Addresses]

<sup>*</sup>Merged in [Sep 2020](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/pull/3265)